# How can I use jQuery to assign every element in a class its current height to its data-height attribute?

Tags: jquery

So if I were dealing with just one element, I could use the following:

```
$("#id").attr( "data-height" , $("#id").css("height") );
```

But is there any way to do this with every element in a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.myElem').each(function() {

    $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('data-height', $this.height());

});
```

You could also just use the `.data()` method

```
$('.myElem').each(function() {

    $this = $(this);
    $this.data('height', $this.height());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.className').children().each(function(i, obj) {
  $(obj).attr('data-height', $(obj).css('height'));
});
```